# Achieving thread safety in a payment service library

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I wrote this code a while ago, which is an excerpt of a payment service library:

```
# recover a transaction details from the Wirecard API
module Wirecard
  module Elastic
    class Request
      class Transaction < Base

        attr_reader :merchant_id, :transaction_id, :payment_method

        def initialize(merchant_id, transaction_id, payment_method)
          @merchant_id    = merchant_id
          @transaction_id = transaction_id
          @payment_method = payment_method
        end

        # calling request
        def request
          @request ||= Request.new(query_uri: query, payment_method: payment_method).dispatch!
        end

        # processed response
        def response
          @response ||= Response.new(request: request, action: :transaction).dispatch!
        end

        # address we want to access on the API
        def query
          @query ||= "merchants/#{merchant_id}/payments/#{transaction_id}"
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

One of my methodologies to abstract methods into new subclasses and compose is to spot private methods which are achieving the same goal, and put them away into a new class. This is especially useful to respect the famous [rules of Sandi Metz](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers).

When it doesn't seem the class will ever need to be interchangeable, I don't use the dependency inversion principle. That would be the case with a XML scraper because it sounds like we could extend it to an alternative JSON scraper, for instance.

All that to say, in some cases I basically put the new subclass into a method and memoize it, then instantiate it only when needed, like in my example.

First, is this a fine way to code in your opinion? I've read so many different code styles, I'm not sure about anything at this point.

Now I'm wondering, is it thread-safe to go *up and down* like this? I'm quite new with this concept of thread safety and I've read a lot about atomization, making things stateless, which looks a lot like a functional way to code to me.

After all, I instantiate a new class, but what I pass to it in my example comes from a few instance variables I set at initialization of the parent class, the I/O should always be the same, right?

If it isn't good, what should I change in my example?

Comment: To the person who edited my question and changed the subject : the point is absolutely not related to the payment service. It's a general question about methodology to achieve thread safety in Ruby.

Comment: Is the refactoring you asked about moving the Response#dispatch! method from the Request class to a new Response class? If so, please mention this in your question and add some code from the Response class. If not, please go into more detail about your refactoring.